# Laravel querying from MySQL table containing more than 150k records

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have a table with 27 columns and contains more than 150k rows.

When I am trying to get a count of a query select where `Population` are 900 rows, and the Recipient table contains more than 150k rows.

So I have to repeat all the 150k for the all of 900 rows.

```
$pops=Population::all();
foreach ($pops as $pop){     
$pop["count"]=
                Recipient::where('population_id',$pop->id)
                ->whereIn("recipients.employment_condition",[0,1,3])
                ->where("recipients.has_car","!=",0)
                ->where("recipients.has_land","!=",0)
                ->count();
}
```

This is what make the server wait about 45 seconds and gave me an internal server error - how to optimize something like this?

**Note:** I have made 4 of the Recipient columns as indexes with no good experience!

[image]

Comment: please attach tables and indexes definition

Comment: And provide the generated SQL.

Answer (score 0):

For standard SQL it's quite trivial query, and one, not 900 separate queries in loop.

```
select p.id, count(r.population_id) from population p
left join recipients r on (p.id = r.population_id
  and r.employment_condition in (0,1,3)
  and r.has_car !=0
  and r.has_land !=0
)
group by p.id
```

Or even better

```
select p.*, ifnull(counter,0) from population p
left join 
  (select 
      r.population_id, 
      count(*) counter 
   from recipients r 
   where 
     r.employment_condition in (0,1,3)
     and r.has_car !=0
     and r.has_land !=0
   group by r.population_id
) c on (c.population_id = p.id)
```

And execute it as raw query.

[DB Fiddle example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f0b8c15d86682034a974d01cbe0ac878)